# PHP issues displaying image gallery

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a gallery with PHP. I want to get all of the images out of a folder and then display them in rows of 3. I kind of have it working but the first 2 images mess up.

This is what I've tried:

```
$images = glob("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/gallery/img*.{png,jpg,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
echo '<table width="100%>';
$count="-1";
foreach($images as $image) {
    if ($count%3 == 1) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    $url=str_replace("/home/#####/public_html/gallery", "", $image);
    echo '<td width="33%"><div class="gallery">';
    echo '<img onclick="window.location='.$url.'" src="'.$url.'" alt="Image Alt" width="400" height="300">';
    echo '</div></td>';
    if ($count%3 == 3) {
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    //echo $count;
    $count++;
    //echo "|".$count;
}
if ($count%3 != 1) {
    echo ',</tr>';
} 
echo '</table>';

//echo print_r($images);
```

This works kind of but it makes this:

[image]
(These are just stock photos, the real photos are a bit.. offensive)

I know I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what!

Comment: Can you share the actual HTML that is generated. Makes it easier to see what is going wrong.

Comment: The photos are all.. and I can't exactly inspect element on a phone..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some errors in your code (see comments). Maybe try this:

```
$images = glob("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/gallery/img/*.{png,jpg,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
echo '<table style="width:100%">'; // error was here (missing ")
$count = 0;  // error was here (counter = "-1")
foreach ($images as $image) {
  // start <tr> on 0
  if ($count == 0) {
    echo '<tr>';
  }
  $url=str_replace("/home/#####/public_html/gallery/", "", $image);
  echo '<td style="width:33%"><div class="gallery">'; // alternative
  echo '<img onclick="window.location='.$url.'" src="'.$url.'" alt="Image Alt" width="400" height="300">';
  echo '</div></td>';
  // end tr at 3
  if ($count == 3) {
    echo '</tr>';
    // reset counter
    $count = -1;
  }
  $count++;
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I think it would be better to show what are errors in his code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have trouble with your `$count` initial value.

Try this:

```
$count="3";
foreach($images as $image) {
    if ($count%3 == 0) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    $count++;

    ...
```